# How Does Pathauto for Drupal 8.x Determine Generate URL Status?

Tags: path-aliases

I would like to turn off the "Generate Automatic URL Alias" for all existing content in my Drupal 8 instance. How do I do that? According to [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1167612) D7 used a table: pathauto_state. From what I can see there is no pathauto_state table in the D8 database. After migrating a website from D6 to D8 with many carefully crafted URL aliases every node is now set to "Generate automatic URL alias" by default. So every time a user edits some old content and saves, the auto-generator kicks in and blows away the old alias unless the user remembers to untick the box. I desperately need to set the "Generate automatic URL alias" to FALSE for all existing content either through the GUI or else through MySQL statements or some other method. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: This issue contains a clue https://www.drupal.org/node/2802289#comment-11789148